# Vue import from node_modules not working with default vue project with apache virtual host

Tags: node.js, vue.js

If i do:

```
npm init vue@latest
```

it install an then i run

```
npm run dev
```

Everything works, but when i make an apache virtual host i and run the site from the browser directly the console gives an error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

At the line

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
```

i have read: [Getting started with Node.js modules: require, exports, imports and beyond](https://adrianmejia.com/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/)

That clarifies a lot but not the error, who has an idea? It looks as if it it trying to look for a local module but it needs to look in node_modules

Comment: Im running Vue3

Comment: And node.js 20 with npm ans yes i did npm install

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem i had to run npm run build but that was not the only step. In this setup npm generates both a js file and a new index.html in the /dist folder so pointing my virtual host to the /dist folder solves my problem